# Getting and displaying data from a MySQL database using user input

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to create a webpage where the user enters an ID number into a HTML form, the ID number is used to fetch the data associated with that ID from a MySQL database and and the data is displayed on the webpage. However, I don't know how to use input from a form to get specific data from the database and then display it back on the webpage. Can anyone help me? I've included my Node.js and HTML files below. Thanks!

index.js

```
'use strict';

const express = require("express"); 
const app = express(); 

const bodyParser = require("body-parser") 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true})); 

var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '123',
  database: 'jobs'   
}); 

conn.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Database connected.');   
});

const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

app.post('/show', function(req,res){

    var id = req.body.jobID;

    var sql = `SELECT job FROM healthcare where id='${id}'`;
    conn.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Data fetched.")
        res.json(result);
    });
}); 

app.listen(PORT,HOST);
```

job.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <body>

        <h1>Enter the job ID </h1>

        <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/show">

            <input type="text" id="jobID" name="jobID">

            <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >

        </form>

        <p>Data should go here </p>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the API directly from the form, you should use an axios function to call the API, then when your API returns a response you can receive it inside you axios function.

Something like this:

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const baseUrl = 'https://localhost:8080';
        let jobID = $('#jobID').val();
        //Create a FormData object to build key-value pairs of information before
        //making a POST HTTP request.
        let webFormData = new FormData();
        webFormData.append('jobID', jobID);
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: baseUrl + '/show',
            data: webFormData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        }).then(function(response) {
            //handle API response here
        }).catch(function(error) {
            //handle errors here
        })
}
```

How this script works is that when you click on your submit button for the form, the data is retrieved and sent to the API using an axios function which can then help in getting the response that your API returns. You need to add this in your frontend either in a script tag or a javascript file, you also need to import axios before you can use the axios functions. On a side note since your API is only retrieving data, it should just be a GET, not a POST as you are not creating anything new in the database. Also do take note on how to use placeholders in your SQL query to prevent SQL Injection.